# Split JS string via Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have   `MMYY` pattern ( credit card expiry)

I need to analyze each section (01 and 14) : So I tried :

```
'0114'.split(/\d{2}/i) //  ["", "", ""]
```

It actually see 2 digits as a separators and hence I get nothing.

However , I've managed to do it with :

```
'0114'.match(/\d{2}/ig) //["01", "14"]
```

But I wonder about `split`.

Can I do it *also* with `split` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example:

```
"1234".split(/(?=..$)/) => ["12", "34"]
```

A generic solution for strings of arbitrary length appears to be impossible, the best we can get is something like:

```
str.split(str.length & 1 ? /(?=(?:..)*.$)/ : /(?=(?:..)+$)/)
```

Comment: positive lookahead of _____ ?

Comment: positive look ahead include the char itself ? I mean (changed a bit to test) `"1234".split(/(?=..)/i)` yield `["1", "2", "34"]` . why do i get also 34 ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: lookarounds match "between" characters, two dots without `$` match in two places: `1^2^34`.

Comment: what about "123456" ? why it doesnt split the string to 12,34,56 ?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
   '0114'.split(/(?=..$)/)
```

Answer (score 1):

No reason to use regex - I'd simply use substring:

```
var str = '0114';
var month = str.substr(0, 2);
var year = str.substr(2, 2);
console.log(month, year); // 01 14
```

Comment: Thanks for the laugh, but I, for one, can appreciate @h2ooooooo's alternative solution. :)