# Split a string to groups of 2 chars using split?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have this simple string :

`"a1a2a3"`

Is there any regex expression which can be used with `split` command so it will split the string to a pairs ? :

`["a1","a2","a3"]`  ?

I've tried this :

`"a1a2a3".split(/(?=..)/)`

But it returns `["a", "1", "a", "2", "a3"]`

p.s.

*I can do it with `Match` but im looking (if exists) for the regex expression which can help me using `split`.*

Comment: What's your motivation for wanting to retain characters using a method that's meant to remove characters?

Comment: how high does this go? a1-a100...beyond? a1-9,b1-9, etc?

Comment: I think I've see an answer with split, a few months ago, but I don't find it.

Comment: @dystroy Are you talking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543903/split-js-string-via-regex])? , if you do , it doesnt work with "a1a2a3"

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `match`?  Is this more of an academic question?

Comment: @bergi This is not a duplicate question. the other question uses `match`.

Comment: It is possible, but you need to know the length of the string before using `split` (2 different regex is used for each of the case: odd-length and even-length). Without knowing the length of the string, I can't think of any way to achieve this with JS regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh can you supply an answer for length 8 ? ( for example)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`split` for even length string:

```
str.split(/(?=(?:..)*$)/)
```

`split` for odd length string, the last entry has single character:

```
str.split(/(?=(?:..)*.$)/)
```

Those are basically look-aheads that check whether the number of characters ahead is odd or even. It takes advantage of the fact that the number of characters ahead at all the split positions have the same parity as the length of the string.

The pattern in the (even version) look-ahead is `(?:..)*$`, which checks for even number of characters `(?:..)*` before the end of the string `$`. (Note that non-capturing group `(?:pattern)` is used here, otherwise, capturing group will create extra entries in the `split` result). Similar explanation applies for the odd version.

Note that `.` [excludes several new line characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp): `\n`, `\r`, `\u2028` or `\u2029`. It will produce unexpected result for string containing such characters. Replace `.` with `[\s\S]` (or other equivalent construct) to make it works for all cases.

---

For practical purpose, `match` is the right tool for the job:

```
str.match(/..?/g)
```

For example:

```
"1234567890".match(/..?/g)
> [ "12", "34", "56", "78", "90" ]

"1234567890".match(/..?/g)
> [ "12", "34", "56", "78", "9" ]
```

**The solution can be extended to group of n characters:**

```
str.match(/.{1,<n>}/g)
```

For example:

```
"123456789012345678901234567890".match(/.{1,7}/g)
> [ "1234567", "8901234", "5678901", "2345678", "90" ]
```

It simply takes advantage of the greedy quantifier and creates groups of n characters, before running out of characters to match for the last group.

Same as above, you may want to change `.` to `[\s\S]` to make it work for all cases.

Comment: finally . this can be shorten to unary condition into 1 expression...`str.length%2==0? /../:/../`

Answer (score 5):

I already answered this in chat. You really should be using `String.prototype.match`.

Can be done with split? Technically, yes. You can split it by `/(..)/` and then filter out the blank strings.

```
"a1a2a3".split(/(..)/).filter(function(a){
    return a !== '';
});
```

Comment: or `"a1a2a3".split(/(..)/).filter(Boolean)`

Comment: @CrazyTrain Nice! Let's chop off a byte and use String instead. `"a1a2a3".split(/(..)/).filter(String)`

Comment: @AakilFernandes The `Boolean` function will cast each string to a boolean true/false. Since an empty string is a falsey value, those values will be filtered out in the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are all possible format of input string, but I assume it's some letter followed by some numbers.

If so you could try:

```
var str = 'abc123d56efg8t5'
var res = str.split(/([a-z]+[0-9]+)/).filter(Boolean);
```

**output:**

```
["abc123", "d56", "efg8", "t5"]
```