# Jquery .when() how to use?

Tags: jquery

having a bit of trouble with my jquery (as usual). I need one function to execute only after the first one is complete, but I'm having trouble with the syntax.. I've been reading about .when and callbacks but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm not quite sure how to format my functions :-( Any help?

```
        $('#buttonone').hover(function () {
            $('#descriptionone').fadeIn(400);},
        function () {
                $('#descriptionone').fadeOut(400);
        });


       $('#buttontwo').hover(function () {
            $('#descriptiontwo').fadeIn(400);},
        function () {
            $('#descriptiontwo').fadeOut(400);
        });
```

I'm just really confused where the .when goes! Any help would be appreciated :-)

edit: sorry about the confusion, I meant that I need the second function where '#buttontwo' hovers needs to execute after the first function where '#buttonone' hovers! The issue right now is that it's executing before the first one is finished fading out and it's overlapping! Thanks!

Comment: How are you running into the overlapping issue? are you hovering over the buttons to quickly?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah it's overlapping when I move to the other button too quickly (before the first one has faded out). I need to like.. delay the second one from fading if the other one is still fading out or something, as both of them are in the same place and they overlap bad! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.when` is usually used for asynchronous events like ajax, so try using the fadeIn callback:

```
$('#buttonone').hover(function () {
     $('#descriptiontone').fadeIn(
         400,
         function () { // executed after fadeIn completes
             buttontwoHover();
         }
     ),
     function () {
       $('#descriptionone').fadeOut(400);
     });
});

function buttontwoHover(){
  $('#buttontwo').hover(function () {
      $('#descriptiontwo').fadeIn(400);},
    function () {
      $('#descriptiontwo').fadeOut(400);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Unfortunately I'm really confused by this code, most specifically the function after the fadeIn time on the third line -- can you explain a little about what you did? Thanks so much!

Comment: What do you really want to do? Do you want to be able to hover #buttontwo (and execute its functions) only after #buttonone has been hovered or do you want to execute the fadeIn from #descriptiontwo only after the fadeIn of #descriptionone?

Comment: After that comment I just realized a flaw in my jquery planning so this isn't really that relevant anymore (u_u), but i'd still like to know for the future! I want #buttontwo's functions to only be executed after #buttonone's functions are completed and faded out.

Comment: So the thing is, you have two functions that are executed after interacting with #buttonone: The first ($('#descriptionone').fadeIn(400)) is executed when you mouseover the button, the second ($('#descriptionone').fadeOut(400)) when you mouseout the button.
Accordingly you have two callbacks that you can specify, one for fadeIn and one for fadeOut.
In my example you allow after the fadeIn of #descriptionone the hover on #buttontwo.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use promises here : `fadeIn` takes a callback as second argument and this callback is executed when the fading is complete.

```
$('#buttontwo').hover(function () {
     $('#descriptiontwo').fadeIn(
         400,
         function () { // executed after fadeIn completes
             $('#descriptiontwo').fadeOut(400);
         }
     );
});
```

Comment: Oops! Sorry I should have been more clear -- I need the entire second  chunk of functions to execute after the first chunk of functions -- sorry! The fadeIn and fadeOuts work fine :-)

Comment: Off-topic , Hi dystroy , did you see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18419843/859154) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, I hadn't. This is interesting, thanks (and I hope you enlightened the room that was so harsh to you yesterday!).

Comment: @dystroy when someone calls me Id*** (as you said , _"you don't call someone **** just because you don't know the answer"_)--,  I prefer not to talk to them....

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#buttonone').hover(function () {
 $('#descriptionone').fadeIn(
     400,
     function () {
          $('#buttontwo').trigger('hover');//trigger the second hover function in callback
     }
 );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/AcquB/)**

Try this

I guess this is what you need.

```
var a = false;
$('#buttonone').hover(function () {
    $('#descriptionone').fadeIn(400);
    a = true;
},

function () {
    $('#descriptionone').fadeOut(400);

});

$('#buttontwo').hover(function () {
    if (a == true) {
        $('#descriptiontwo').fadeIn(400);
    }
},

function () {
    if (a == true) {
        $('#descriptiontwo').fadeOut(400);
    }
    a = false;
});
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: hmm, they're still overlapping -- thanks for the response though! so frustrating u_u I tried switching the first 'a = true;' to the fadeOut of ('#descriptionone') because I think that's where I only want a to be true, after ('#descriptionone') has faded out! But I don't think it's true after it's faded, just before or during. Is there a way to make 'a = true;' *after* it has faded out? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I thought you want to do it each time. so that after you have finished hovering over buttontwo, if you have the buttontwo to be hovered again you have to hover over buttonone .

Comment: Yeah I want to be able to do it each time, but they're still overlapping right now :-(

Comment: I thought you want to do it each time. so that after you have finished hovering over buttontwo, if you have the buttontwo to be hovered again you have to hover over buttonone .

Comment: Ah no, sorry! I basically need it so that if you come directly from button1 to button2, button2 doesn't execute until button1 is done, but if you like move off of button2 and then back to button2 it will execute fine!

Comment: ok if you want so either you can delete 'a=false;' in the above code or just try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/AcquB/1/