# Split Integer into 2 digits and put into array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, int

(Must read to understand exactly what I need)
I  would like to create a program that takes a number is input, such as: 12345 and then splits this number into 2 digit numbers and store it in a array. The array must look like this: [0]=45 [1]=23 [2]=1 . This means that the splitting of the numbers must start from the last digit of the number and not the first.

This is what I have until now:

```js
var splitCount = []; // This is the array in which we store our split numbers
//Getting api results via jQuery's GET request
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCJwchuXd_UWNxW-Z1Cg-liw&key=AIzaSyDUzfsMaYjn7dnGXy9ZEtQB_CuHyii4poc", function(result) {
    //result is our api answer and contains the recieved data
    //now we put the subscriber count into another variable (count); this is just for clarity
    count = result.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;
    //While the subscriber count still has characters
    while (count.length) {
        splitCount.push(count.substr(0, 2)); //Push first two characters into the splitCount array from line 1
        count = count.substr(2); //Remove first two characters from the count string
    }       
    console.log(splitCount) //Output our splitCount array
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but the problem with this is that if there are 5 digits for example: 12345 the the last digit will be in an array by itself like this: [0]=12 [1]=34 [2]=5 but I need the last array to have 2 digits and the first should be the one with one digit instead like this: [0]=1 [1]=23 [2]=45

Comment: Try starting from the end of the string

Comment: But its an int? can you help me?

Comment: Make it a string by concatenating it to a "", then back to an int with paresInt() method

Comment: You state that the output of `12345` should be like `[0]=45 [1]=23 [2]=1` in the first part of your question, but like `[0]=1 [1]=23 [2]=45`, in the last part. Which is it?

Answer (score 3):

Split the string by using different regex for odd and even string lengths, `Array#map` it using `Number`, and `Array#reverse` the array:

```js
function splitToNumbers(str) {
  return str.match(str.length  % 2 ? /^\d|\d{2}/g : /\d{2}/g).map(Number).reverse()
}
    
console.log(splitToNumbers('1234567'));

console.log(splitToNumbers('123456'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet that fulfills the task. The function stores the values in the array `myArray`, and then outputs the array to a `<p>` element. The number is entered in the input box. Feel free to change this later.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Input field
  var input = document.getElementById('num');1
  // Length of the array storing the numbers
  var myArraySize = Math.floor(input.value.length / 2) + (input.value.length % 2);
  // The array storing the numbers
  var myArray = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < myArraySize; i++) {
    myArray[i] = input.value.slice(2*i,2*i+2);
  }
  // Output the array
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myArray;
}
```

```html
<input id="num" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" />
<p id="demo">Result</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string with a regular expression and reverse the array.

This answer is heavily inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18419843/1447675).

```js
var regex = /(?=(?:..)*$)/;

console.log('12345'.split(regex).reverse());
console.log('012345'.split(regex).reverse());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex or expensive calculations. You might simply do as follows;

```js
var n = 250847534,
steps = ~~Math.log10(n)/2,
  res = [];
for(var i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
  res.push(Math.round(((n /= 100)%1)*100));
  n = Math.trunc(n);
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Amending your code a little

```js
var splitCount = []; // This is the array in which we store our split numbers
//Getting api results via jQuery's GET request
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCJwchuXd_UWNxW-Z1Cg-liw&key=AIzaSyDUzfsMaYjn7dnGXy9ZEtQB_CuHyii4poc", function(result) {
    //result is our api answer and contains the recieved data
    //now we put the subscriber count into another variable (count); this is just for clarity
    count = result.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;
    //While the subscriber count still has characters
    while (count.length) {
        splitCount.push(count.substr(-2)); //Push last two characters into the splitCount array from line 1
        if(count.length > 1) {
           count =  count.substr(0, count.length - 2); //Remove first last two characters from the count string
        } else {
           break;
        }
    }       
    console.log(splitCount) //Output our splitCount array
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach your problem, from nice one-liners using regexes (like [Ori Dori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41704830/6738706) or [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41706060/6738706)) to [Redu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41715476/6738706) that works directly on numbers, avoiding strings.

Following the logic of your code example and comments, here is an alternative that converts the number to a string, loops over it backwards to extract two digits at a time, converts these back to a number (with the unary plus operator), and outputs this number to a result array:

```js
function extract(num) {
  var s = '0' + num, //convert num to string
    res = [],
      i;
  for(i = s.length; i > 1; i -= 2) {
    //loop from back, extract 2 digits at a time, 
    //output as number,
    res.push(+s.slice(i - 2, i));
  }
  return res;
}

//check that 12345 outputs [45, 23, 1]
console.log(extract(12345));

//check that 123456 outputs [56, 34, 12]
console.log(extract(123456));
```